# How to process queue in asyncio using ProcessPoolExecutor and run_in_executor?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement a pattern where I'm:

- Using an async library to get data and add it to a queue
- Using `ProcessPoolExecutor` to process this data as the work is cpu bound

Below is a minimal reproducer of the code I have so far and it appears to work, however, since I have very little experience with asyncio, I'm wondering if I'm missing something or if it could be improved somehow? Thanks.

```
import asyncio
import os
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from random import random

aqueue = asyncio.Queue()
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)


async def produce_item(item):
    async with sem:
        print(f"produce {item}")
        await asyncio.sleep(random() * 2)  # simulate waiting for i/o
        await aqueue.put(item)


async def process_queue(executor):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        item = await aqueue.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        else:
            loop.run_in_executor(executor, process_item, item)


def process_item(item):
    print(f"process {item}, pid {os.getpid()}")
    time.sleep(random())  # simulate long processing time


async def supervisor():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        processor_task = asyncio.create_task(process_queue(executor))
        await asyncio.gather(
            *[produce_item(i) for i in range(100)]
        )
        await aqueue.put(None)
        await processor_task


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(supervisor())
```

Comment: I see you're calling `loop.run_in_executor()` but you're not awaiting the result? Is that intentional? Also, why is there the semaphore?

Comment: Ah thanks for that. So I'm guessing the way to do this would be to append each future to a list in the infinite loop and then await them all at the end once we've broken out? And the semaphore is there to simulate a connection pool in the real code - sorry, should have noted that.

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. You can spawn multiple `process_queue()` tasks and then put `await` before `run_in_executor()`: `await loop.run_in_executor(executor, process_item, item)`. **OR** you can put the future into a list and use `add_done_callback` to signal when the future ended (to remove it from the list of tasks)...